# GKE Kubernetes Ingress is not using annotated reserved static IP even tho it has been created

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I have created a new reserved static IP in my GCP.
See the screenshot marker **1.**
[image]
However my ingress resource is still using the generated ip (screenshot marker **2.**)

In the Ingress' YAML file you can see I annotated the static-ip name.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s-be-31465--b5c10175cf4f125b":"HEALTHY"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s-fw-default-teamcity--b5c10175cf4f125b
    ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s-tp-default-teamcity--b5c10175cf4f125b
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s-um-default-teamcity--b5c10175cf4f125b
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name":"teamcity-static-ip"},"name":"teamcity","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"teamcity","servicePort":8111}}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: teamcity-static-ip
  creationTimestamp: "2019-11-12T13:57:41Z"
  generation: 1
  name: teamcity
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3433973"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/teamcity
  uid: 6484482e-0554-11ea-af7d-42010a8400aa
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: teamcity
    servicePort: 8111
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.190.86.15
```

That's why I am confused why it is not assigning it to the Ingress resource as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GKE: ingress loadbalancer does not use configured static IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421716/gke-ingress-loadbalancer-does-not-use-configured-static-ip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the name of the annotation: `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` , this works only with global IP.

And if you look at the screen your ip is a regional one: `europe-west-1`.

Create a global IP, delete and recreate the ingress and it should work ;)

Comment: being a global IP is not the only requirement. In my cluster, the ingress was not using the IP even being global.

The only solution I found was to go to http://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/advanced/forwardingRules/list and manually add a forwarding rule myself. Everything seems fine now. I still don't know why k8s didn't use the IP I asked it to use.

Comment: That seems like a special case, nether had any issue with global ip... Maybe something changed following an update?